# The stored procedure sp_MShelpcolumns is missing in Azure SQL server

Tags: azure-sql-database

**My Problem**

The stored procedure  [sys].[sp_MShelpcolumns] is missing in Azure SQL server.

**My Query**

1. Should we be creating this SP on the Azure SQL Server?
2. Or is it existing in another name or another location?
3. Or do we have am equivalent SP in Azure SQL Server?

Please suggest a way to have this missing system generated Stored Procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer depends on why you want it.  That is a very old, undocumented stored procedure, and so it was not exposed in Azure Sql Database.  If you want to examine the catalog metadata about the columns in a table, use the [sys.columns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-columns-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

If you need that stored procedure because some old product depends on it, you could try creating it yourself.  It's just a stored procedure built on the older catalog views, and you can script it out from any SQL instance.  Note that you won't be able to create it in the 'sys' schema so this will only work if the client executes it without the schema qualification (which is probably the case as this proc pre-dates the idea of the 'sys' schema).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes. There is a old product which depends on this stored procedure. I will try to  use sys.columns as suggested .

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround you can create your own stored procedure containing a query like below:

```
SELECT tbl.table_schema + '.' + tbl.table_name as "TABLE_NAME", COLUMN_NAME AS [Output]
    ,ORDINAL_POSITION, col.*
    --,prop.value AS [COLUMN_DESCRIPTION]
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES AS tbl
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS AS col ON col.TABLE_NAME = tbl.TABLE_NAME
INNER JOIN sys.columns AS sc ON sc.object_id = object_id(tbl.table_schema + '.' + tbl.table_name)     AND sc.NAME = col.COLUMN_NAME
WHERE tbl.table_schema <> 'sys' and tbl.table_name = 'TableName'
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply . I will try your solutions and let you know.